# Swish import RDF

Tags: prolog, rdf, swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

Is it possible to import an rdf file from a URL into Swish?

I.e. something like:

`myload:- load_rdf('www.myrdf.com').`

Then I could query `?-rdf(A,B,C)`

Answer (score 0):

With the `Semweb` package and using Swi-Prolog locally, it's easy:

```
use_module(library(semweb/rdf11)).

use_module(library(semweb/rdf_http_plugin)).

rdf_load('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Amsterdam').
% Parsed "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Amsterdam" in 0.13 sec; 5,120 triples
```

Comment: This does not work in swish - the online swi prolog.

Comment: You're right. Swish is a small subset of Prolog and apparently doesn't load the semweb packages. When I try `use_module(library(semweb/rdf11)).` (or `rdf_db`) it returns true but `rdf/3` doesn't exist.